# jQuery help wanted ...

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site there is a pop up window in right. and have a button. My query is , if i click that button then the pop up windows will come to left and if i again click that button then the pop up window will go back it's previous place i mean right. it's like slideToggle . I have try something . but it comes only left but it's not going back . How to do it ?

```
<script>
function goto(){    
    //animate to the div id.
    $(".pop_up").animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)});

}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".red_sec").click(function(){
    $(".pop_up").animate({left:'-560px'});
  });
});
</script>
```

Sorry for my bad English skill .

Thanks

Comment: You define `function goto` but never use it, and you never seem to be trying to move it back. This seems like a very half-hearted attempt.

Comment: Actually I am new in javascript/jQuery . I am just trying to learn . Thanks for your suggestion @Kolink

Comment: You should not use jQuery until you are at least somewhat competent with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, this will give a `toggle effect`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".red_sec").click(function(){
       $(".pop_up").animate({'left': ($(".pop_up").position().left == -560)?100:-560});
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9E2AM/)

Comment: Thank you very much Rajaprabhu . it is working great .

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, I'd say. Provide the `.pop_up` element with a [data-attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) and use it to determine which way the animation should go:

```
function goto(){    
    var direction = $(".pop_up").attr('data-lr');
    $(".pop_up").animate( {left: direction} );
    $(".pop_up").attr('data-lr',direction === '+=100' ? '-=100' : '+=100');

}

$(".red_sec").click(goto);
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4spkx/)

Comment: Thank you every body . Problem solved :)